# how to do PHP object reference with an arrow pointer operator to a dynamically generated value

Tags: php

I want to be able to do an object reference with a pointer operator to a dynamically generated value

```
//Jobs

class Jobs 
{
    private $orderid;
    private $quantity;
    private $contactno;
    private $contactname;
}
```

Hence I will create object keys

```
$keys = array(
    'orderid',
    'quantity',
    'contactno',
    'contactname'
);
```

Then do

```
$size = 4;
$i = 0;

//object instantiation

$jobObject = new Jobs();

$row = array('894949','45','08097577580','Emi');

for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){

    //This is my challenge

    $jobObject->$keys[$i] = $row[$i];
}
```

I am very sure there should be a way to get the value of $keys[$i] that can be referenced by "$jobObject->" to do object property initialization.

I have tried to enclose $keys[$i] with braces by doing

```
$jobObject->{$keys[$i]} = $row[$i];
```

Yet it throws error. Please I need help on how to get this working or a way out.

Comment: you cannot assign a value directly to a **protected** property, you should change to **public** to use your solution

Comment: ok.. but given the property is public, how can i do $jobOject-> followed by the value of $keys[$i] that's my main challenge

Comment: Encapsulation should work. What was the thrown error ? `$jobObject->{$keys[$i]} = $row[$i];`

Comment: @amachreetamunoemi i've added a complete answer

Comment: thanks @fxbt, it works with encapsulation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use brackets for variable variables. You'll then be able to dynamically create your object:

```
$jobObject->{$keys[$i]} = $row[$i];
```

Take a look at the php documentation this subject: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign a value directly to a protected property.
Take a look to [visibility reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

The correct way to achieve what you want is the following.

```
<?php
class Jobs 
{
    // Change access to public
    public $orderid;
    public $quantity;
    public $contactno;
    public $contactname;
}

$keys = array(
    'orderid',
    'quantity',
    'contactno',
    'contactname'
);

$size = 4;
$i = 0;

//object instantiation

$jobObject = new Jobs();

$row = array('894949','45','08097577580','Emi');

for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){

    // This is the way

    $jobObject->{$keys[$i]} = $row[$i];
}

var_dump($jobObject);
```